# Partial enum compiled in runtime - alternative

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to do something like a `partial enum`. If I know C# has no support for this. My idea is to do `Dictionary<PartialEnum, MyClass>` in `MyClass2`. Dictionary contains some properties loaded from file and I want to have a possibility to add some other "properties" (members of `PartialEnum`). I am using the Roslyn so I can compile some "second" part of *enum* during runtime but don't know how to do it. (`partial static class` is also not supported so I cannot use `public readonly` members)

```
MyClass{
  string value;

  public string Value{
     get{ return value;}
  }
}

MyClass2{

  private Dictionary<PartialEnum,MyClass> properties;

}
```

I can use `string` like key but it is not very nice. So is it possible to do something like:

```
partial enum PartialEnum{
 Name,
 Group, ...
}
```

and runtime compiled part

```
partial enum PartialEnum{     
 runTimeLasName,
 runTimeTitle, ...
}
```

Comment: `enum` offers support for named values at compile time. What benefit are you attempting to get from compiling them at run-time? Whatever code accepts an `enum` is really just accepting whatever value the `enum` uses, in C# this defaults to `int`. Your dynamic enumerated values can be used at run-time without any compilation if you supply the relevant value as simply cast it to your enumerated type on entry to the method that takes the type. It won't correlate to any known value, but it will keep it's underlying value. At run-time you won't care about that anyway.

Comment: `static partial class` is supported. But I'm not sure that will help you, since you can't create one part of a class at compile time and then add something to it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you don't actually need an `enum` here. You want to add some values to it at runtime, which means `enum` doesn't fit your needs. But you can create a class that does. Something like:

```
class PartialEnum
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, PartialEnum> Values =
        new Dictionary<string, PartialEnum>();

    public string Id { get; private set; }

    private PartialEnum(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public static PartialEnum GetValue(string id)
    {
        PartialEnum value;
        if (!Values.TryGetValue(id, out value))
        {
            value = new PartialEnum(id);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static PartialEnum Name { get { return GetValue("Name"); } }

    public static PartialEnum Group { get { return GetValue("Group"); } }
}
```

If you want to use one of the predefined values, access the static property (e.g. `PartialEnum.Name`). If you want to use a runtime-defined value, use the `GetValue()` method (e.g. `PartialEnum.GetValue("runTimeLastName")`).